# Unable to synchronize threads in Android Studio

Tags: android, thread-safety, synchronized

I have a background class named "TCP client" that sets a boolean to true whenever a state change is detected in hardware. And runOnUIThread in main activity detects this and updates UI which are switch buttons, in order not to trigger the OncheckedChangeListener I set the listener to null, change state, then set the listener to its original one. But during runtime OncheckedChangeListener is still triggering. I guess this is a synchronization problem.

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public SwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener switchListener;
public com.suke.widget.SwitchButton switch;
public static boolean switchflag=false;
int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    switch = findViewById(R.id.lightSwitch);
    runThread();

    switchListener = new SwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchButton view, boolean bChecked) {
                if (bChecked) {
                    Log.d("button", "light is on");
                    connection.tcpClient.sendMessage("li1_1");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Button", "light is off");
                    connection.tcpClient.sendMessage("li1_0");
                }
            }
    };
    switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(switchListener);
}

    private void runThread() {
    i = 0;
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (i++ < 1000) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(connection.tcpClient.getStatusFlag()) {
                                Log.d("main", "got Status");
                                updateUI();
                                connection.tcpClient.setStatusFlag(false);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void updateUI() {
    try {
        switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        switch.setChecked(switchFlag);
        switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(switchListener);
    }catch (NullPointerException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

I am not getting where to use the synchronized.

Comment: make your boolean variable volatile

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
 runThread();
```

below

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(switchListener);
```

Also Replace

```
switch.setChecked(lightFlag);
```

With

```
switch.setChecked(switchFlag);
```

Comment: Tried this no luck

Comment: @user7434651 Can you share the whole class? i can not find where lightListener is.

Comment: lightFlag vs switchflag is another typo. please correct it and then try again.